# Coroutines in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, coroutine

It seems like [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) are normally found in higher level languages.

There seem to be several different definitions of them as well. I am trying to find a way to have the specifically called coroutines in C like we have in Lua.

```lua
 function foo()     
     print("foo", 1) 
     coroutine.yield() 
     print("foo", 2) 
 end
```

Comment: Your question is what exactly?

Comment: Thanks.

I have searched for many hours but that's the thing... I am looking for something production ready.

Comment: Hi Tony how to have corountines in C/C++, I want to avoid threading

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safe cross platform coroutines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974170/safe-cross-platform-coroutines)

Answer (score 2):

There's no language level support for coroutines in either C or C++.

You could implement them using assembler or fibres, but the result would not be portable and in the case of C++ you'd almost certainly lose the ability to use exceptions and be unable to rely on stack unwinding for cleanup.

In my opinion you should either use a language the supports them or not use them - implementing your own version in a language that doesn't support them is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks Joe

I was reading about doing this in assembly but I could not find any examples. Rolling my own solution in ASM would be suicide

Comment: [coroutines were available since C++20?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43503656/995714)

Answer (score 2):

There is a new (as of version 1.53.0) coroutine library in the Boost C++ library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html

I'm unaware of a C library--I came across this question looking for one.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, C++ provides coroutines natively as part of [C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines).

Concerning the C language, they are not supported natively but several libraries provides them. Some are not portable as they rely on some architecture-dependent assembly instructions but some are portable as they use standard library functions like *setjmp()*/*longjmp()* or *getcontext()*/*setcontext()*/*makecontext()*/*swapcontext()*. There are also some original propositions like this [one](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/coroutines.html) which uses the C language trick from the [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

N.B.: On my side, I designed this [library](https://github.com/Rachid-Koucha/crtn).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - neither C nor C++ has support for coroutines.  However, a simple search for "C coroutine: yields the following fascinating treatise on the problem: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html, although you may find his solution a bit - um - impractical

Comment: Thanks.

I have searched for many hours but that's the thing... I am looking for something production ready.

Comment: C++17 will likely have a coroutine implementation.  Current Proposal here: https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3722.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of coroutine libraries for C++. [Here's one](http://rethinkdb.com/blog/improving-a-large-c-project-with-coroutines/) from RethinkDB.

There's also [mine header-only library](https://code.google.com/p/libglim/source/browse/trunk/test_cbcoro.cc), which is tailored to be used with callbacks. I've tried [Boost coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) but I don't use them yet because of the [incompatibility with valgrind](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=306171). My implementation uses `ucontext.h` and works fine under valgrind so far.

With "standard" coroutines you have to jump thru some hoops to use them with callbacks. For example, here is how a working thread-safe (but leaking) Cherokee handler looks with Boost coroutines:

```
typedef coroutine<void()> coro_t;
auto lock = make_shared<std::mutex>();
coro_t* coro = new coro_t ([handler,buffer,&coro,lock](coro_t::caller_type& ca)->void {
  p1: ca();  // Pass the control back in order for the `coro` to initialize.
  coro_t* coro_ = coro;  // Obtain a copy of the self-reference in order to call self from callbacks.
  cherokee_buffer_add (buffer, "hi", 2); handler->sent += 2;
  lock->lock();  // Prevents the thread from calling the coroutine while it still runs.
  std::thread later ([coro_,lock]() {
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (400));
    lock->lock();  // Wait for the coroutine to cede before resuming it.
    (*coro_)();  // Continue from p2.
  }); later.detach();
  p2: ca();  // Relinquish control to `cherokee_handler_frople_step` (returning ret_eagain).
  cherokee_buffer_add (buffer, ".", 1); handler->sent += 1;
});
(*coro)(); // Back to p1.
lock->unlock(); // Now the callback can run.
```

and here is how it looks with mine:

```
struct Coro: public glim::CBCoro<128*1024> {
  cherokee_handler_frople_t* _handler; cherokee_buffer_t* _buffer;
  Coro (cherokee_handler_frople_t *handler, cherokee_buffer_t* buffer): _handler (handler), _buffer (buffer) {}
  virtual ~Coro() {}
  virtual void run() override {
    cherokee_buffer_add (_buffer, "hi", 2); _handler->sent += 2;
    yieldForCallback ([&]() {
      std::thread later ([this]() {
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (400));
        invokeFromCallback();
      }); later.detach();
    });
    cherokee_buffer_add_str (_buffer, "."); _handler->sent += 1;
  }
};
```